# Как добавить изображение в кнопке "поделиться" Фейсбука?

Tags: javascript, share, facebook-widgets

Сейчас я использую этот код:

```
$('#fb_shareWidget').click(function(){
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]='+encodeURIComponent(GLOBAL_blablacar)+'&p[summary]='+encodeURIComponent(GLOBAL_summary)+'&p[url]='+encodeURIComponent(GLOBAL_url)+'&p[images][0]='+encodeURIComponent(GLOBAL_images),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=700,height=400');
});
```

Но вместо моей картинки и текста, указанного в джаваскрипте, я вижу лишь текст со страницы, на которой расположена кнопка, и безо всякой картинки. Какой нужно написать код, чтобы добавить картинку в виджет "поделиться"?